# Работа с очень большими файлами в Python. Помогите найти утечку памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x, память

День добрый.
Подскажите как обрабатывать файлы большого размера в Python.
Имеется file.txt размером в 25ГБ.

Задача - отфильтровать этот файл построчно и записать в outfile.txt.
Вот мой код:

```
import multiprocessing


def run():
    file = open('file.txt', 'r')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
    pool.imap_unordered(work, file)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


def work(line):
    if len(line.strip()) >= 6:
        outfile.write(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'a')
    run()
    outfile.close()
    file.close()
```

Проблема заключается в том, что где-то здесь течет память. Через время программа заваливается по нехватке памяти. Помогите найти утечку памяти, или подскажите какими инструментами можно мониторить потребление памяти в программе.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_memory_algorithm

Comment: Я в курсе, что это такое. Более того, я даже воспользовался правильным методом построчного чтения файла в своем коде. Но память все-равно протекает, и я прошу указать мне на мои ошибки в коде, а не кидать бесполезные ссылки на википедию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, файлы *не* потокобезопасны в Python. А вы ведь пишете из нескольких потоков в один открытый файл. Некоторые рецепты что с этим делать можно [прочесть здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135091/write-thread-safe-to-file-in-python)

Самое безопасное, наверное - это писать в выходной файл в одном потоке, а то, что туда нужно писать - класть в очередь в потоках. Но в вашем случае обработка данных довольно лёгкая, упираться всё будет именно в запись файла и смысла в многопоточности тут вообще нет.

Ну либо можно в каждом отдельном потоке заново открывать файл на запись, писать туда и закрывать, но ускорение от этого опять же вряд ли будет.